# Inner join of tables with criteria not like

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

```
Sentoni (id, person_id, duty_id, dayofduty, dayoff)
Ranks(id, rank)
Personel (id, rank, fullname)
```

In all tables the id is the primary key. Sentoni.person_id corresponds to personel.id and ranks.id corresponds to resonel.rank .
I would like to get the personel.id , ranks.rank and personel.fullname of outer join of Sentoni where the dayofduty IS NOT A SPESIFIC day , let’s say 2015-04-04.

I am deeply confused with the join of these tables.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this

```
SELECT p.id, r.rank, p.fullname 
FROM Sentoni s
INNER JOIN Personel p ON p.id = s.person_id
INNER JOIN Ranks r ON r.id = p.rank
WHERE s.dayofduty <> ...;
```

This should select the required information, provided that there's a respective record in each of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question, I think you are trying to do Full Outer Join on three tables in MySQL.

There is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL. See [7.2.12. Outer Join Simplification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html) and [12.2.8.1. JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> You can emulate `FULL OUTER JOIN` using
>   UNION (from MySQL 4.0.0 on):
>
> with two tables t1, t2:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> UNION
> SELECT * FROM t1
> RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> ```
>
> with three tables t1, t2, t3:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
> UNION
> SELECT * FROM t1
> RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
> UNION
> SELECT * FROM t1
> RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
> ```

If you want only common records to fetch; you can use inner Join:

```
SELECT p.id, r.rank, p.fullname 
FROM Sentoni s
JOIN Personel p ON p.id = s.person_id
JOIN Ranks r ON r.id = p.rank
WHERE s.dayofduty <> 'Your_date';
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, the upper answer was just what I was looking for.

Comment: Hmmm :) Hope you don't have any uncommon records in these three tables :)